# Random slow content download, while TTFB remains low

Tags: performance, magento, varnish

I'm developing a Magento2 website, everything is running well for now, except a random issue I can't figure out how to solve.

The website is using Varnish, and all pages have a varnish cache HIT, with a very low TTFB about 30ms and low content download too (about 40ms)

But randomly, the download timing increases to more than 2 seconds, and on the next page visit it will go down to normal 40ms.

Same issue on all browsers, so not a browser issue.

Would someone have an idea ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are so many factors at play. The most important thing is whether or not you can simulate the issue and predict when the issue will appear again.

Once you're able to simulate, you need to determine what type of resource is slow:

- Is it the graphical rendering of the page in the browser?
- Is there a 3rd party JS resource that is slow?
- Is it the actual TTFB of the main page that is slow for that resource?

Please use your browser's development tools and check the breakdown in the networking tab. With enough attempts, you'll be able to spot the issue. When you do, please add a screenshot of the breakdown in this question.

In parallel, you can keep the following command running to identify requests that took more than 2 seconds to process:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "Timestamp:Resp[2] > 2.0"
```

You can also add the output to your question.